# MySQL Show rows that exist in one table but not it another

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

1. `organisation`

   - `organisation_id`, `organisation_name`
2. `srp_reseller_buffer`

   - `organisation_id`, `property_id`

I want to write a MySQL query which shows me all the records in organisation except those that are in `srp_reseller_buffer` and have a `property_id` of X

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM organisation
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM organisation 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN srp_reseller_buffer 
                ON srp_reseller_buffer.organisation_id = organisation.organisation_id 
            WHERE srp_reseller_buffer.property_id is NULL
```

And that SQL query is not working. It just shows me a list of all the organisations in organisation table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple left join?

```
SELECT organisation.*
FROM organisation
LEFT JOIN srp_reseller_buffer ON
    (organisation.organisation_id = srp_reseller_buffer.organisation.id AND property_id = 'X')
WHERE srp_reseller_buffer.organisation_id IS NULL
```

Records which don't exist on the 'right' side (srp_reseller) will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a condition from the outer `SELECT` statement in the inner one.

Just look at the inner `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM organisation 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN srp_reseller_buffer 
        ON srp_reseller_buffer.organisation_id = organisation.organisation_id 
   WHERE srp_reseller_buffer.property_id is NULL
```

this will probably return <strike>at least one record</strike> no records.

Now, since you don't include a condition from the outer `SELECT` statement, this query will return exactly the same result for every record in the `organisation` table. This should be equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM organisation
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (<the result from the inner query>)
```

Because `<the result from the inner query>` is the same for all records in `organisation` (and especially <strike>*not*</strike> *is* empty), you get the whole `organisation` table.

#### Edit

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM organisation o
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM srp_reseller_buffer
            WHERE srp_reseller_buffer.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
              AND srp_reseller_buffer.property_id = X
    )
```