# fetch email id of those employee who has resigned

Tags: mysql, linq

My first table is `emp_master`

```
empid    emailid
1        aaa@yahoo.com
2        ww@yahoo.com
3        rr@yahoo.com
4        dd@yahoo.com
```

My second table is `emp_resignation`

```
empid    status
1        resigned
3        resigned
```

Now I want to fetch only those `emailid` whose `status` is not `resigned` by joining both the table.

**Output**

```
ww@yahoo.com    
dd@yahoo.com
```

Can any one provide me link, query for this above problem????
Please, friends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Show rows that exist in one table but not it another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808877/mysql-show-rows-that-exist-in-one-table-but-not-it-another)

Comment: Your question title is the opposite of what you ask for in the question.

Comment: You are asking for linq query or some link?

Comment: yes i am asking for linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN, and select all the rows with no match.

```
SELECT emailid
FROM emp_master AS m
LEFT JOIN emp_resignation AS r ON m.empid = r.empid
WHERE r.empid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group join (can't say whether you linq provider can translate it, but its completely valid with Linq to SQL or default EF provider for MS SQL):

```
from e in db.emp_master
join r in db.emp_resignation
   on e.empid equals r.empid into g
where !g.Any() || g.Any(r => r.status != "resigned")
select e.emailid
```

Comment: That doesn't look like MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar your query does not look like LINQ

Comment: thank u so much sir for ur kind help.i realy appreciate this.thak you once again sir.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL script:

```
SELECT emailid 
FROM emp_master em
JOIN emp_resignation er
ON em.empid = er.empid 
WHERE er.status != 'resigned'
```

Linq:

```
from em in emp_master
join er in emp_resignation
on em.empid equals er.empid
where er.status != "resigned"
select em.emailid;
```

Comment: sorry no output is coming

Comment: i have not check linq query.i have check sql query but no output is coming but thank u so much for showing your interest in my problem and thank u so so much.

Comment: Sure, np. If `emp_resignation` contains a `resigned` entry for all `empid`s then no results will be shown.

Comment: So is this the problem? The queries should return results.

Comment: sir i have just posted a problem now.can u please provide me solution for that??